# What is the genus of a union of curves? How are they classified?

Tags: curves, algebraic-curves, plane-curves, singularity

Consider a cubic plane curve like this:

$$y(y - x^2 - 1) = 0$$

which is clearly the "union" of a line ($y = 0$) and a parabola ($y = x^2 + 1$) that have no points in common (not even the point at infinity), what kind of curve is this? How do I classify it?

This is a degree 3 curve, and I'm unable to find any singularity, so it should be of genus 1. However, I'm not fully convinced by that, and I think I'm making a mistake: intuitively, this should allow a rational parametrization, so it should be of genus 0. Can somebody please shed some light on this?

Comment: Your curve has singularities at the points $(i,0)$ and $(-i,0)$. Normally we look at curves over an algebraically closed field, so I assume over the field of complex numbers.

Comment: More generally, the union of curves has singularities at the points where the curves intersect. In the projective plane $P^2(\Bbb{C})$ a degree $m$ and a degree $n$ curve intersect at $mn$ points counted with multiplicity (Bezout's theorem). There are various notions of genus for curves with singularities, but you have to wait for someone who is better informed. I don't know how genus is defined when the curve is reducible. Sorry :-(